# Bounded entire function constant

Tags: complex-analysis

if $f$ is entire and $f(z) < |R|\varepsilon(R)$ for large $|z| = R$ where $\varepsilon\rightarrow0 $ as $R\rightarrow\infty$, show $f(z)$ is constant.

I have used $|g(z)| = |f(z) - f(0)|/z$ and shown it is bounded and therefore constant since it is also entire. Now I know $f(z) = az + b$. How can I show $a = 0$?

Comment: Otherwise $|f(z)|\sim|a||z|\not<|z|\epsilon(|z|)$ for $|z|$ large enough.

Comment: And additionally, $g(z)\to0$ as $z\to\infty$ by condition, thus $g(z)=0$.

Comment: Curious that you did the tricky part and not this.

Comment: There were plenty of other posts here I could use for help on the first part...thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{az+b}{z} = a$$
and by your assumption $f(z)/z \to 0$ as $z\to\infty$.